# Outlook Mac application not considering Daylight Saving time in ICS in case of appointments having in both DST and non-DST period

Tags: outlook, icalendar, ical4j

I am trying to schedule an appointment in my calendar which occurs every Saturday starting from Jan11 .The first occurrence of the meeting is on Jan 11th 6:15 PM -7:15 PM GMT +5:30 ( 4:45 AM to 5:45 AM PDT i.e GMT -08:00) and the last being March 14, 2020 5:15:00 PM - 6:15 PM GMT +5:30 (March 14th 4:45 AM to 5:45 AM PDT i.e GMT -07:00).
When I open outlook Mac calendar in IST(GMT +5:30) time zone , I see that the last occurrence is being reflected on calendar as 6:15 PM -7:15 PM instead of 5:15:00 PM - 6:15 PM.This is because the outlook mac app , is not considering the DST properly from the ICS.
But if I open the same ics in google calendar/Outlook web app/Outlook windows app appointments are scheduled with right time considering the Day light saving time.

Below is the ICS attached to the email.

```
PRODID:-//MYCalendar//NONSGML Version 1//EN
VERSION:2.0
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Los_Angeles
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:18831118T120702
TZOFFSETFROM:-075258
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
RDATE:18831118T120702
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:STANDARD
DTSTART:19181027T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
RDATE:19610924T020000
RDATE:19500924T020000
RDATE:19550925T020000
RDATE:19600925T020000
RDATE:19540926T020000
RDATE:19530927T020000
RDATE:19590927T020000
RDATE:19520928T020000
RDATE:19580928T020000
RDATE:19570929T020000
RDATE:19560930T020000
RDATE:19450930T020000
RDATE:19510930T020000
RDATE:19490101T020000
RDATE:20081102T020000
RDATE:20071104T020000
RDATE:19851027T020000
RDATE:19911027T020000
RDATE:19961027T020000
RDATE:20021027T020000
RDATE:19641025T020000
RDATE:19701025T020000
RDATE:19811025T020000
RDATE:19861026T020000
RDATE:19971026T020000
RDATE:20031026T020000
RDATE:19691026T020000
RDATE:19751026T020000
RDATE:19801026T020000
RDATE:19871025T020000
RDATE:19921025T020000
RDATE:19981025T020000
RDATE:19631027T020000
RDATE:19681027T020000
RDATE:19741027T020000
RDATE:19191026T020000
RDATE:19621028T020000
RDATE:19731028T020000
RDATE:19791028T020000
RDATE:19931031T020000
RDATE:19991031T020000
RDATE:20041031T020000
RDATE:19181027T020000
RDATE:19671029T020000
RDATE:19721029T020000
RDATE:19781029T020000
RDATE:19881030T020000
RDATE:19941030T020000
RDATE:20051030T020000
RDATE:19661030T020000
RDATE:19771030T020000
RDATE:19831030T020000
RDATE:19891029T020000
RDATE:19951029T020000
RDATE:20001029T020000
RDATE:20061029T020000
RDATE:19651031T020000
RDATE:19711031T020000
RDATE:19761031T020000
RDATE:19821031T020000
RDATE:19841028T020000
RDATE:19901028T020000
RDATE:20011028T020000
END:STANDARD
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
DTSTART:19180331T020000
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
RDATE:19190330T020000
RDATE:19180331T020000
RDATE:19740106T020000
RDATE:20070311T020000
RDATE:20080309T020000
RDATE:19480314T020000
RDATE:19750223T020000
RDATE:19550424T020000
RDATE:19600424T020000
RDATE:19660424T020000
RDATE:19770424T020000
RDATE:19830424T020000
RDATE:19860427T020000
RDATE:19540425T020000
RDATE:19650425T020000
RDATE:19710425T020000
RDATE:19760425T020000
RDATE:19820425T020000
RDATE:19530426T020000
RDATE:19590426T020000
RDATE:19640426T020000
RDATE:19700426T020000
RDATE:19810426T020000
RDATE:19520427T020000
RDATE:19580427T020000
RDATE:19690427T020000
RDATE:19800427T020000
RDATE:19510429T020000
RDATE:19570428T020000
RDATE:19630428T020000
RDATE:19680428T020000
RDATE:19560429T020000
RDATE:19620429T020000
RDATE:19730429T020000
RDATE:19790429T020000
RDATE:19610430T020000
RDATE:19670430T020000
RDATE:19720430T020000
RDATE:19780430T020000
RDATE:19840429T020000
RDATE:19500430T020000
RDATE:19850428T020000
RDATE:19880403T020000
RDATE:19940403T020000
RDATE:20050403T020000
RDATE:19890402T020000
RDATE:19950402T020000
RDATE:20000402T020000
RDATE:20060402T020000
RDATE:19900401T020000
RDATE:20010401T020000
RDATE:19910407T020000
RDATE:19960407T020000
RDATE:20020407T020000
RDATE:19970406T020000
RDATE:20030406T020000
RDATE:19870405T020000
RDATE:19920405T020000
RDATE:19980405T020000
RDATE:19930404T020000
RDATE:19990404T020000
RDATE:20040404T020000
RDATE:19420209T020000
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=1SU
DTSTART:20200308T031746
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=SU
DTSTART:20201101T031746
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:19700119T062939Z
ORGANIZER:mailto:XXX@gmail.com
UID:MEQ6H_79ptdgclzt@KxijUD26wIoRpbH
SEQUENCE:0
RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;WKST=SU;COUNT=10;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=SU;BYSETPOS=2
ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE:mailto:XXX@gmail.com
DTSTART;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20200109T063000
DTEND;TZID=America/Los_Angeles:20200109T073000
SUMMARY:DEV Monthly Second sunday 10 occurences
TRANSP:OPAQUE
CREATED:20200109T141737Z
LAST-MODIFIED:20200109T141737Z
STATUS:CONFIRMED
LOCATION:SomeWhere
DESCRIPTION:NO Description
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Answer (score 0):

Outlook has a reputation for not dealing well with upcoming daylight saving 
https://www.google.com.au/search?q=outlook+calendar+1+hour+daylight+saving

Also most likely Outlook ignores the provided timezone definition and goes with it's own definition to be consistent within it's calendar.